# Serializing/deserializing exceptions without stack trace using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to create a class with a `java.lang.Exception` stored as a field. Also I am trying to exclude stack trace from serialization/deserialization using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

class ExWrapper {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"stackTrace"})
    public Exception ex;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExWrapper{" +
                "ex=" + ex +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ExWrapper exw = new ExWrapper();
        exw.ex = new Exception("Oops");
        String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(exw);
        System.out.println(str);
        ExWrapper exW = mapper.readValue(str, ExWrapper.class);
        System.out.println(exW);
    }
}
```

The result error is quite surprising, Jackson cannot find the `message` field:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "message" (class java.lang.Exception), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "cause"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"ex":{"cause":null,"message":"Oops","suppressed":[],"localizedMessage":"Oops"}}"; line: 1, column: 32] (through reference chain: ExWrapper["ex"]->java.lang.Exception["message"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1179)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1592)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1570)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3173)
    at Example.main(Example.java:25)
```

Well, there is only `getMessage` and no `setMessage` in `Throwable` class so it seems a bit reasonable unless you try to remove `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation. It works like a charm: it serializes and deserializes back properly and missing setter for `message` is suddenly not a problem. Adding `"message"` to ignored fields also make it work (yet without an exception message).

I tried to randomly step in Jackson code using debugger and found out that when `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is missing, eventually `ThrowableDeserializer` methods are called and they are not called when the annotation is present. `ThrowableDeserializer` seems to have some hacks specific to exception message. My guess is that `ThrowableDeserializer` is not viable when the stack trace is missing and Jackson falls back to default java bean serializer.

The question is what exactly is going on here and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Version 2

`ThrowableDeserializer` class extends `BeanDeserializer` so these two share some code how to create and deserialise a `POJO`. `Exception` is not a regular `POJO` and should be handled differently. Since it does not provide to many setters we need to use constructor to create it with message and other fields we can skip. To register constructor we can use `MixIn` feature:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Exception.class, ExceptionMixIn.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(Throwable.class, ThrowableMixIn.class);

        ExWrapper exW = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, ExWrapper.class);
        exW.ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties("stackTrace")
abstract class ExceptionMixIn extends Exception {

    @JsonCreator
    public ExceptionMixIn(@JsonProperty("message") String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties("stackTrace")
abstract class ThrowableMixIn extends Throwable {

    @JsonCreator
    public ThrowableMixIn(@JsonProperty("message") String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class ExWrapper {

    public Exception ex;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExWrapper{" +
                "ex=" + ex +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code for a `JSON` with exception with a cause prints:

```
java.lang.Exception: Opps
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(ValueInstantiator.java:229)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ThrowableDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(ThrowableDeserializer.java:65)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Root oops
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(ValueInstantiator.java:229)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ThrowableDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(ThrowableDeserializer.java:65)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:530)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:528)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:449)
    ... 8 more
```

As you can see, exception has default `stackTrace` and `stackTrace` from `JSON` payload is skipped.

### Version 1

I did not dig it too much but enabling `allowSetters` solves this problem:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"stackTrace"}, allowSetters = true)
public Exception ex;
```

Your code with this change prints:

```
{"ex":{"cause":null,"message":"Oops","localizedMessage":"Oops","suppressed":[]}}
ExWrapper{ex=java.lang.Exception: Oops}
```

Comment: This way `stackTrace` will be deserialized if present in `str` (in case the source of `str` is external). It is probably OK for my case but still, can it be fully ignored? Also the magic of the original code is not yet revealed.

Comment: (My comment above applies only to Version 1)